# React Native + jest + shallow rendering = unexpected token error

Tags: mobile, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I'm trying to test a React Native component using jest and shallow rendering.

However, calls to `ShallowRenderer.render()` results in an error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
>           at eval (native)
>           at Object.eval (components/list-conditions.js:1:244)
>           at Spec.eval (**tests**/components/list-conditions-test.js:14:48)

The test code is very simple, I don't even need to have an assert statement to get that error:

```
jest.dontMock('../../components/list-conditions.js');

const React = require('react');
const TestUtils = require('react-addons-test-utils');

const ListConditions = require('../../components/list-conditions.js');

describe('ListConditions', () => {

  it('renders buttons', () => {
    var renderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
    renderer.render(<ListConditions conditions={['a', 'b']} />);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same Unexpected `token error`, and adding a `.babelrc` file in the project root file with the followings helps me

```
{
  "presets": [
     "react",
     "es2015"
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you're using the latest version of React Native, you can simply use the `babel-preset-react-native` module and write `{ "presets": ["react-native"] }` in your `.babelrc` file.